# ASP.NET MVC 3 Performance Issue - Single Machine, Unable to profile or break

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got a strange issue with an ASP.NET MVC 3 App where on my desktop machine loading the home page of my MVC app takes 30+ seconds.  Using miniprofiler, I see that the very first step takes 95% of the time and subsequent rendering & processing is very fast.  I've tried breaking into the code and always end up with the "no code available" window.

It gets even more strange in that once I attach the VS performance profiler, the issue goes away.

I haven't seen this before and would love any guidance or feedback.

Thanks,

Seth

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I can actually "answer" this one, except to say that I am no longer seeing this issue after using Nuget to remove Ninject, and reinstall it.  Strange the same source with the same assembly was fine on 3 other dev machines, but ... resolved!